# Composer локально

Tags: php, composer

в локальной сети компании нет доступа в интернет. Встал вопрос с Composer, можно ли настроить Composer, что бы он ходил в локальный репозиторий (в локальной сети) и уже с него устанавливал пакеты. Туда пакеты будем добавлять сами.

Comment: у вэб-разработчика нет доступа в интернет? серьезно, такое бывает? ставьте лучше вопрос о смене места работы.

Comment: "Туда пакеты будем добавлять сами". На флешке приносить?

Comment: Да на флешке, интернета то нет)

Comment: @teran почему у вэб-разработчика? Может это какой-то ПК для работников, которые будут с готовым проектом работать? И доступ в инет отрублен по соображениям безопасности

Comment: @СергейМишин если с готовым проектом, то проект должен быть развернут вместе с зависимостями и обновлять там нечего.

Comment: Может кто-то, что-то посоветует?

Comment: ну composer - это пакетный менеджер, он ищет пакеты в репозитории, следовательно вам нужно как-то по менять это репозиторий на локальный в настройках composer

Comment: Согласен, что нет интернета - это уже "глобальная" проблема)

Comment: @teran ну проект же дорабатывается и новые зависимости появляются, которые потом композером могут быть подтянуты. Не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение, вдруг кому поможет. Есть плагин **Satis**

**Документация**
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

**github**
https://github.com/composer/satis

Answer (score 1):

В `composer.json` указываете свои репозитории.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
],
```

[Документация](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)

Comment: Это я нашёл, а как его правильно настраивать?

Comment: А как вы ведете контроль версий?

Comment: Через гит, но сторонние пакеты я туда включать не хочу. или для каждого создать свой репозиторий и туда заливать?

Comment: Не, репозиторий - это есть какая-то директория. Вам нужно иметь какой-то приватный пакетный репозиторий, как говорит документация `composer`
вот ссылка https://packagist.com/

Comment: По сути у вас можно сказать как приватные пакеты будут. настроите приватный пакет-менеджер, он вам скорее всего выдаст адреса пакетов, а далее зададите тип `composer` и пропишите все что надо

Comment: спасибо сейчас почитаю

Comment: а случайно нет примеров приватного пакет-менеджер

Comment: К сожалению нет(